# Is there any difference in meaning or nuance when the adjective follows the noun in Georgian?

Tags: syntax, word-order, georgian, adjectives, branching

Many languages allow the order of adjectives compared to nouns to vary, but for different reasons:

1. Some languages have very free word order in which case there is little difference between **adj + noun** and **noun + adj**.
2. Some languages, the Romance languages are a good example, favour one order, **noun + adj** but also allow the other order **adj + noun** on at least some nouns. But when this is done the meaning of the adjective will be different, or at least have a different enough nuance that a translation into another language will choose a different word to map it to.

My question is: In the Georgian languages which normally has **adj + noun** are instances of **noun + adj** a case of 1. above, or of 2. ?

(The example of *noun + adj** I saw was "პიცი პატარა" (pitsi patara). "პიცი" (pitsi) means "pizza" and "პატარა" (patara) means "small".)

Comment: This is language specific. I know there isn't a Georgian SE for you to post this in, but  since this question isn't cross-linguistic, maybe you want to rephrase it so it fits the ["wide" point of view](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) of the Linguistics SE?

Comment: I can't think of any way to change it into wider point of view a question. It would be a shame to remove it from a site suffering so badly of lack of questions )-:

Comment: What about asking something related to parameters, as in [this question about French](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/how-does-parameter-theory-square-the-phenomena-of-french-adjectives-that-branch)?

Comment: I don't know much about parameters really though I get what it means in principle. In fact I found that question about French quite difficult to read.

Comment: While we apparently have a *no single-language questions* rule, [it has been questioned on meta](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/24/are-questions-about-a-single-language-on-topic) in September 2011 with seemingly no support! I have therefore asked a new question about this rule on meta: **[What's the reasoning behind our policy against questions on a single language, and is it good?](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/238/whats-the-reasoning-behind-our-policy-against-questions-on-a-single-language-a)**